KONG Same Route with Both JWT and API Key Authentication, How to Make Both Work Simultaneously?
I am currently using KONG Gateway, and I've enabled two authentication mechanisms on the same Route in a Service: JWT Authentication and API Key Authentication. When I use one of the authentication methods, the other one causes the request to be rejected.
Specifically:

When I use JWT authentication, I get the error message "message": "No API key found in request".
When I use API Key authentication, I get the error message "message": "Unauthorized".

Here is my configuration:

Enable JWT Authentication Plugin:
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/routes/my-route/plugins \
     --data name=jwt


Enable API Key Authentication Plugin:
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8001/routes/my-route/plugins \
     --data name=key-auth



I want to be able to use either JWT or API Key authentication based on what the request carries, rather than being limited to just one authentication method.
My question:

How can I configure KONG so that both authentication mechanisms work on the same Route, and the correct one is used based on what credentials are provided in the request?
Is there any setting or plugin that can help resolve this issue?


You could create a consumer which will be used to identify as "Anonymous" and configured both authentication plugin to use that customer to "pass" authentication.
First, create an anonymous consumer:
curl -sX POST localhost:8001/consumers \
--data '{"username": "anonymous"}'

Afterward, use the id of this newly created anonymous consumer and add it to config.anonymous field of both authentication plugins:
curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8001/routes/my-route/plugins/{key-auth-plugin-id} \
   --data '{"name": "key-auth", "config": { "anonymous": "{anonymous-consumer-id}"}}'

curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8001/routes/my-route/plugins/{jwt-plugin-id} \
   --data '{"name": "jwt", "config": { "anonymous": "{anonymous-consumer-id}"}}'

This will essentially create an OR flow between both authentication plugin, when the first plugin failed (jwt), Kong will understand that the request is not authenticated and use key-auth to perform authentication again.
Afterward, add a Request Termination plugin to the anonymous consumer:
curl -sX POST localhost:8001/consumers/anonymous/plugins/ \
  --data '{"name": "request-termination", "config": { "status_code": 401, "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "body": "{\"error\": \"Authentication required\"}"} }'

This will cause the request that failed every authentication plugins to get a 401 error back with Authentication required in the body.

I added a new consumer in Konga which is anonymous, and I set both configurations to this. However, it causes my verification to bypass directly.

@LanLin I forgot the last step that is to add request termination. I've edited the answer.

thank you, this can work.
